# Send Json POST Method HttpWebRequest Vb.NET

Tags: vb.net

I already have how to send a JSON by the POST method in Vb.NET, here I leave the code:

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("myurl")
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/json"
request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer 80mgkm6D60OtY16pzs93WoYmx2kzTgf3CELERMVg")
Dim PostString As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyClase)
Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostString)
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
Dim dataStream1 As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
dataStream1.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
dataStream1.Close() 'sends request
```

Question: Is there a simpler way (less code) to do the same thing.

I thank you very much

Question: Is there a simpler way (less code) to do the same thing.

Comment: As a whole, doesn't look too dissimilar to what I would expect.  Would suggest maybe reading up on the Using clause for IDisposable implementations.  Other than that, might want to hit up the crew on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much it was solved with the HttpClient library

In the previous way, the error 422 came out in the API server and the JSON was not processed

```
Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
Dim request_json = MyJSON
Dim content = New StringContent(request_json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", myToken)
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
Dim result = client.PostAsync("myurl", content)
Dim result_Json_string = result.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

[httpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0) is what you should be using for new development. Note that HttpClient should NOT be wrapped in a using block.

```
Public client as new HttpClient()

Public Function makeHttpRequest()
    Try
  
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("HEADERNAME", "HEADERVALUE")

        Using response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.PostAsync("url", new StringContent("YourJsonString", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            Dim responseBody As String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        End Using
    Catch e As HttpRequestException
        'handle exceptions
    End Try
End function
```